# how to show a component on button onClick in react

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to show a react-component on click of a button

```
const Header = () => {
return(
    <div role="button" className="user-logout" onClick={logoutUser}> // return the component when this is pressed
       <i className="fas fa-sign-out-alt user--nav--icon"></i>
       Logout
    </div>
)}
```

Comment: Do you mean to show a component onClick?

Comment: @JoeJohnson yes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's how I'd go about showing a component onClick

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Header = () => {

const [showComponent, setShowComponent] = useState(false);

const handleClick = () => setShowComponent(!showComponent) //hides component if shown, reveals if not shown

return(
    <div role="button" className="user-logout" onClick={handleClick}> // return the component when this is pressed
       {showComponent && <i className="fas fa-sign-out-alt user--nav--icon"></i> Logout}
//returns the <i> element and 'logout' text if showComponent is true
    </div>
)}
```